# Get RSSI of Wifi when doing discovering in iOS?

Tags: ios, wifi, fingerprint, rssi

I am planning to do indoor location using wifi fingerprint technique and I would like to know if iOS allows me to get the RSSI of the networks around...i know android allows me doing this but just want to confirm it is also possible on iOS.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't do it via public API on iOS. There is a public CoreWLAN framework for such purpose, but it is only available on OSX.
There is however a private api: Apple80211 private framework. There is no public documentation for it, but something you can find [here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/). You can't create apps for App Store using it, but if you need something for yourself - you are welcome.